# Debug Android spring framework: print the sent requests

Tags: android, spring, debugging, logging

I use the spring framework for Android to make calls to a rest server. I can't find a way for debugging the sent requests, I would like to print the **raw** body of the requests built by the framework. 
It seems pretty basic but as the framework auto serialize the objects, I can't figure out how to print the **raw** final body.

Is anybody have a solution?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 8):

Try this command:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.RestTemplate VERBOSE
```

(You can find `adb` in `...android-sdk/platform-tools/`)

Comment: Sorry for not commented this before, this trick is helpful in some cases but doesn't give a real way to debug exactly what you want. For the record, I use the Volley framework now, which provides, among other things, much more flexibility.